# flask RESTful service for pdfbox

Tags: python, rest, flask, pdfbox

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import jpype
import jpype.imports
jpype.addClassPath(sys.argv[1])
jpype.startJVM(convertStrings=False)
import org.apache.pdfbox.tools as tools
tools.ExtractText.main(['-startPage', '1', sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]])
```

I use the following python code to call pdfbox.

```
$ ./main.py pdfbox-app-2.0.20.jar in.pdf output.txt
```

But it would be slow to load jar file each time when I want to convert a pdf file. Could anybody providing the flask code to make a RESTful service so that pdfbox can be loaded only once then it will be access to extract text from PDF?

PS. This is tutorial is not good for solving my questions.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

For example, it imports `send_from_directory` which is a little remote from the complete solution. What I need is an example program that can take an input from the REST inteface and save the file somewhere then call the java code then send the file back. Therefore, a single example showing all the three steps is needed.

Comment: Flask is the way to go, check https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/ that gives an example.

Comment: Flask is _a_ way to go. So are Django, FastAPI, Pyramid, ... Which is why questions asking us to find or recommend off-site resources, and those that are primarily opinion-based,  are explicitly _off-topic_ as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: OP, this question is far too broad. With 5k reputation, I suspect you know this.

Comment: I've limited the question to flask only. Please unclose it.

Comment: @user1424739, this is still off-topic. We're not here to write (or find) code for you. Have you done some basic research on Flask? Gone through any tutorials? Found libraries for creating RESTful APIs using Flask?

Comment: @Chris I've added why the tutorial is not the best answer for my question. Again, I don't think this question is off-topic.

Comment: @user1424739 Just curious if you tried anything from my answer? Did it solve your problem of using pdfbox with Flask?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `POST` route in Flask which would receive uploaded PDF file, process it with `pdfbox` and return whatever you need back to user (either text content or text file itself). I **didn't test** this code, it's just **an example to get the idea** how to handle it, hope it will be helpful!

```
"""
Pseudo-code with possible mistakes, not tested, just to get the idea...
"""
import gzip
from io import BytesIO

import jpype
import jpype.imports
import org.apache.pdfbox.tools as tools
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask import request

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

jpype.addClassPath('pdfbox-app-2.0.20.jar')
jpype.startJVM(convertStrings=False)


def allowed_file(filename):
    """ Helper function to figure out if file is a-ok"""
    return '.' in filename and \
        filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    """ Route to upload and process PDF files """
    uploaded_file_name = 'upload.pdf'
    converted_file = 'output.txt'

    # Get the file from the form upload (or any other desired way)
    # If you use curl with -F flag, request will contain 'form' data
    file_data = request.form['file']

    # Save content of file to local disk (e.g. save as .pdf file)
    with open(uploaded_file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(file_data)

    # Call your Java thingie
    try:
        tools.ExtractText.main(['-startPage', '1', uploaded_file_name, converted_file])
    except:
        print('Error processing file.')
        # Do extra post-processing if needed

    # Serve back whatever you need here...
    response = make_response(converted_file)
    gzip_buffer = BytesIO()
    gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb', fileobj=gzip_buffer)

    gzip_file.write(response.get_data())
    gzip_file.close()
    response.set_data(gzip_buffer.getvalue())
    response.headers.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
    response.headers.set('Content-Length', len(response.get_data()))
    response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=converted_file)
    return response
```

Comment: I am the only one to use the server so checking the filename is not needed. What needed is when there is error in calling the jar function, there should be some post-processing code. Also, it should not require users to send the filename along with the file content, only the file content should be sent. In other word,  `curl -v -F file='<'1.txt ...` instead of `curl -v -F file=@1.txt ...` should be used to query the server. The returned results should be compressed to save the network bandwidth. Last, could you please test your code to make sure it works? Thanks.

Comment: @user1424739 I updated my answer to reflect your requirements a bit more, however, the code is still untested and I don't have intention to test it, first because the point is not to get complete solution, that's what some people actually get paid for. The other thing is, I don't know what kind of data you are sending to Web server and what exactly you need to do and serve back. With my snippet, you should get a nice starting point and with a little bit of help from [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) (or StakcOverflow), you should be able to do rest of the things yourself.

Comment: You used a fixed filename on the server side. What if there are concurrent accesses to the server? What should be returned in place of `# Do extra post-processing if needed`?

Comment: I used fixed filename because this is a pseudo-code (as stated in my answer and code snippet) and because I don't have intention to write fully operational web server for you. You should be able to figure out some simple things like those by yourself. Regarding "extra processing", I don't know what is your intention there, you mentioned that you need some "extra post-processing" if calling Java fails, so just handle it and return whatever you need (probably some kind of error?)...

Comment: +10 @errata For even mocking up a pseudo code, for a clearly "give me answers" type question....

Comment: @Akib Rhast Thanks, I appreciate it! I honestly thought that he needs just the idea how to start with Flask and moving his code behind some endpoint...

Comment: @errata I need a minimal working solution. Yours is not as you have not tested it. It is not minimal either.

Comment: @user1424739 How it isn’t? :) You wanted a Flask endpoint which would process pdfbox stuff. I showed you how to create a Flask endpoint which would run the pdfbox stuff from your example. If you run this with adding your code from your example, it would do the job with possibly few tiny changes which an user with your reputation should be able to handle, isn’t it?